# Redirect to controller to another with param in grails

Tags: grails, redirect

I have to redirect to a controller action called `step2` when I get an error

this is the controller

```
 def step2(Example exampleInstance) {
     some code
 }
```

and this is where I catch the error

```
if (errorProp) {              
    redirect(????)
    return
}
```

how can I redirect to the controller and pass the exampleInstance too?
I tried with `t(uri: "/spot/step2")` but I have not been able to pass the `exampleInstance` to `step2`. I also tried `(action:'step2'.....)` but I can't pass exampleInstance this way either. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have better luck using the [chain method](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Controllers/chain.html) on the controller. This way you can pass the model along to the next action.

```
chain(action: 'step2', model: [exampleInstance: exampleInstance])
```

Comment: Or the `forward` method